# How to fix TypeScript issue: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'string' in React component

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, react-typescript

I have the following React typescript component:

```
type CustomTeaser = Exclude<Teaser, TeaserThree>;

const MyCustomBlock = ({ customItems }: Props) => {
  const sixGridData = { items: customItems as CustomTeaser[] };

  return customItems?.length ? (
     <SixGrid data={sixGridData} />
  ) : null;
};

export default MyCustomBlock;
```

The `data.items` property from the child component `<SixGrid>` has also logic to filter the items correctly:

```
 const filteredItems = data.items?.filter(
    (item) =>
      item?.__typename.includes('TeaserOne') || item?.__typename.includes('TeaserTwo')
  );
```

The *props* of this component are typed like:

```
type Props = {
  data: {
    title?: string | null;
    items: (TeaserOne | TeaserTwo)[];
  };
};
```

Now I have a new situation. Inside `<MyCustomBlock>` I have to replace the 6th item in the array with some `jsx`. For now lets keep it simple, I replace it with a `string`:

**Array conversion:**

```
const copyArray = [...(sixGridData as (RelatedItemTeaser | string)[])];
  copyArray[5] = 'foo';
  const newData = { items: copyArray };
// This works fine, but maybe there is a better way to do this
```

And pass the new array data `newData` into the child component:

```
<SixGrid data={newData} />
```

To fix a new Typescript error on the `data` property from `<SixGrid data={newData} />` component (which is because I added `string`), I added `string` to the props type from SixGrid component:

```
export type Props = {
  data: {
    title?: string | null;
    items: (TeaserOne | TeaserTwo | string)[];
  };
};
```

But this creates a new problem:

Inside  component I have logic like:

```
 if (node.type.includes('TeaserOne')) {
    const teaserOne = node as TeaserOneType;

    return (
      <TeaserOne
        key={teaserOne.id}
        url={teaserOne.url}
        title={teaserOne.title}
        // other props...
      />
    );
  }
```

Now I get in above the following Typescript error:

> Property 'type' does not exist on type 'string'.

How do I solve this issue. And am I on the right path to fix this issue (converting the array and pass it into child, so it's rendered on correct position and in the correct components.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of `as` casts introduce type guards:

```
const isTeaserOne = (value: unknown): value is TeaserOne =>
  typeof value === 'object' &&
  Array.isArray(value.type) &&
  value.type.includes('TeaserOne');
```

then you can use it like this:

```
if (isTeaserOne(node)) {
  // now ts knows that node is TeaserOne
  return (
    <TeaserOne
      key={node.id}
      url={node.url}
      title={node.title}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: So will the only solution to update the typescript parts inside the child `<SixGrid>` component? There is no way to do something from `<MyCustomBlock>` component? So I am able to pass in also `string` or `ReactElement` as array items?

Comment: Not the only solution, but the most appropriate is to update `SixGrid` component.
Of course you can do some hacks and inject elements using direct DOM manipulations, but it's the worst you can do.